# Comparing files with different extensions - keep the bigger

Tags: php

I have a folder with lots of pairs of JPG and WEBP files (same name, different extension).

I need to identify which WEBPs are bigger than JPGs (most can be smaller).

I tried the PHP script below - and it´s working. I just wonder if it could be shorter and/or optimized than that.

```
$i = $j = $l = 0;

// Use an array to store the sizes of JPG files
foreach (glob("*.jpg") as $file1) {
    $tamjpg[$i] = filesize($file1);
    $i++;
}

// Use an array to store the sizes of WEBP files
foreach (glob("*.webp") as $file2) {
    $tamwebp[$j] = filesize($file2);
    $j++;
}   

// Use an array to store the names of JPG (same of WEBP files)
foreach (glob("*.jpg") as $file3) {
    $names[$l] = $file3;
    $l++;
}

// As arrays have equal sizes, compare them and return 
// the name of files whose WEBP is greater than the JPG
for ($k = 0; $k < sizeof($tamjpg); $k++) {
    if ($tamjpg[$k] <= $tamwebp[$k]) {
        echo $names[$k] . "<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: How can we 'help'? You haven't shown us what you've done, or indicated what's going wrong with it.

Comment: Hi, Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code you have tried. Goodluck :D

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you may join 2 loops with different extensions into the one. See glob example here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php#110340 and then check exact extension of a file. Also you may collect names and sizes in the same loop. As a result you would get rid of 2 loops.

If you have ONLY webp and jpg files you may do not use glob at all. Use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php and just iterate through list of files.

Besides, if you're sure that webp file goes next to jpg file and there's always a pair of files, you may do everything in one loop. You may create `for` loop with step = 2 and then on each step you'll be able to get access the jpg file and it's pair.

Answer (score 0):

Great Nikita!

Thanks to your guidance I got it:

```
$dir = "/tempdir/";
$fi = new FilesystemIterator($dir, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$fileCount = iterator_count($fi);
$files = scandir($dir);
for ($k = 0; $k < $fileCount; $k+=2) {
    if ( filesize($files[$k]) < filesize($files[$k + 1]) ) echo $files[$k] . "<br />";
}
```